# How do we duplicate/clone a collection in AWS Rekognition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

Can the current collection be replicated with a new collection ID in AWS Rekognition?

Answer (score 1):

There are **no API calls available** to clone/duplicate an Amazon Rekognition face collection.

In fact, you **cannot even 'retrieve' an entry** from face collections. Rather, face collections are used by other API calls (eg `SearchFacesByImage()`).